# Express.js how to retrieve a request IP securely?

Tags: node.js, express

Since I cant use SSL over some servers that are sending sensitive data using `bearer tokens`. I was thinking about assigning an IP address when the user logs in, and attaching it to each JWT in a database, and checking it before refreshing it (short lived access tokens). The problem ive found is that I dont know how to securely retrieve the IP in the backend.

I have seen that you can set a `app.set('trust proxy', true)` to your express initialization and then retrieve ip addresses with `req.ip` , but apparently since app.set trusts proxies, it means that the headers received by express can be modified by an attacker right? So it would be pointless, since anyone could embeed a fake ip.

Is there any alternative to this that is not using ssl, and not using aes to encrypt the bearer tokens?

Comment: Sorry, there is not a way to "securely" request an IP from an client

Comment: I would be looking into why you can't use SSL which should always be enabled in a production environment

Comment: @CaptEmulation I guess I will have to end up convincing the boss somehow

Comment: If you don't want someone to be able to "watch" data packets go by from the middle of the connection (like a sys admin in your ISP), then you need to use SSL.  That is one of the several things you use SSL for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by CaptEmulation, you should **always** enable SSL on production servers especially when authenticating users.

That being said, I believe it is [not possible](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/212705%20/is-it-possible-to-spoof-an-ip-address-to-an-exact-number) to spoof an IP address when sending a request to a server. The IP address is used to route data back to an attacker so it has to be either the attacker’s ISP-assigned, VPN-assigned or proxy-assigned IP.

**IMPORTANT WARNING:** As mentioned by jfriend00, although it is not possible to spoof an IP, without SSL, it is possible to put together a [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack and intercept or manipulate the data that is sent between users and the server.

Comment: Your attacker scenario is not correct if the attacker is a man-in-the-middle that is "sniffing" data packets as they go by (like someone in your ISP could do via some router).  In that case, the IP address is still set to the original user, but someone else is watching the data go by.  Your first part about always enabling SSL is the only good answer here.